# Multi-stage build in Docker shows unknown PATH

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, fastapi, uvicorn

I want to build a Docker image with a multi-stage build. The image is based on FastAPI and Uvicorn.

If I use the following `Dockerfile` for a multi-stage build

```
# Stage 1: Build stage
FROM pytorch/pytorch:2.1.2-cuda12.1-cudnn8-runtime as builder

# set working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends python3 python3-pip git \
    && ln -sf python3 /usr/bin/python \
    && ln -sf pip3 /usr/bin/pip \
    && pip install --upgrade pip

# install python dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN apt-get remove -y git


# Stage 2: Final stage
FROM pytorch/pytorch:2.1.2-cuda12.1-cudnn8-runtime

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends python3 \
    && ln -sf python3 /usr/bin/python

# Copy the installed dependencies from the previous stage
COPY --from=builder /usr/local /usr/local
ENV PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

WORKDIR /usr/src

# Copy your app code
COPY ./app/ ./app/
```

and run it with the following `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.8'

services:

  scraiber_gpt:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      secrets:
        - githubpat
    command: uvicorn app.main:app --reload --workers 1 --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000
    volumes:
      - ./src:/usr/src
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
```

I get

```
Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "uvicorn": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
```

However, for the non-multi-stage build with the `Dockerfile`

```
FROM pytorch/pytorch:2.1.2-cuda12.1-cudnn8-runtime

# set working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends python3 python3-pip git \
    && ln -sf python3 /usr/bin/python \
    && ln -sf pip3 /usr/bin/pip \
    && pip install --upgrade pip

# install python dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN apt-get remove -y git

# Copy your app code
COPY ./app/ ./app/
```

things tend do work. Hence, I wonder how I could make the multi-stage build work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use a virtualenv to manage your dependencies, try this:

```
# Stage 1: Build stage
FROM pytorch/pytorch:2.1.2-cuda12.1-cudnn8-runtime as builder

# set working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1




RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends python3 python3-pip git \
    && ln -sf python3 /usr/bin/python \
    && ln -sf pip3 /usr/bin/pip \
    && pip install --upgrade pip

RUN python -m venv /opt/venv
ENV PATH="/opt/venv/bin:$PATH"

# install python dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN apt-get remove -y git


# Stage 2: Final stage
FROM pytorch/pytorch:2.1.2-cuda12.1-cudnn8-runtime

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends python3 \
    && ln -sf python3 /usr/bin/python

NV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends python3 \
    && ln -sf python3 /usr/bin/python

COPY --from=builder /opt/venv /opt/venv

WORKDIR /usr/src

# Copy your app code
COPY ./app/ ./app/
```

Comment: Many thanks for your input. But don't I need the two commands `RUN python -m venv /opt/venv` and
`ENV PATH="/opt/venv/bin:$PATH"` in the second stage?